# How to create destination (Folder) in PHP while using move_uploaded_file()?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I want to upload files with PHP and i use move_uplload_files to copy them to the destination folder I want, everything works fine with this :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], './uploades/'))
die("success");
else
die("error");
```

But when I try this

```
$rand =  chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122));
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], './uploades/'.$rand))
die("success");
else
die("error");
```

I will get error, and it looks like move_uploaded_files *can not* create folders. How can I do this ?

Basically I am looking for a way to do it like `file_put_contents()` that creates the path if not exist.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

If you need to make multiple folders, such as by passing `a/b/c`, set the third argument to `TRUE`.

You can test if it is already there, and add if not like so....

```
$path = 'abc';

if ( ! is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}
```

Comment: `@mkdir()` would suppress the error, or the best way would be `file_exists`

Comment: So first i should see if it exists and then creat it if its no there right ?

Comment: @Ragez: I think there should be something to do it like `file_put_contents()` does it automatically creates if it not exists.

Comment: @Omeid Herat There is, and it's above :P

Comment: @Omeid: I would like so but I didn't ran in that function so far

Comment: @RageZ Using the error suppressor is rarely a good idea I've found with PHP.

Answer (score 6):

Use something like this:

```
$folder = "uploads"; 
if(!is_dir($folder)) mkdir($folder);
```

[`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) checks if the folder is there.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$path = "upload/";
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
// Remove dangerous characters from filename.
$name = str_replace('..', '', $name);
$name = str_replace('/', '', $name);
$name = str_replace('\\', '', $name);

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)) {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      } else {
        if(file_exists($path.$name)){
            echo "$path$name already exists. ";
        } else {                
            @mkdir($path, 0666, true);  // Create non-executable upload folder(s) if needed.
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path.$name);
            echo "Stored in: $path$name";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file. Allowed are JPG smaller than 2 MB.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the directory first using `mkdir()`

```
  $rand =  chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122));
    mkdir('./uploades/'.$rand);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], './uploades/'.$rand))
    die("success");
    else
    die("error");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if($_FILES['file_up']['type']=='image/jpeg' || $_FILES['file_up']['type']=='image/png' || $_FILES['file_up']['type']=='image/gif')
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_up']['tmp_name'],'uploads/'.time().$_FILES['file_up']['name']);
}
else
{
    echo "Upload only image file..";
}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable