# PHP File Upload Creating Directory

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, directory

So I have a file upload portion on my website where the user can upload any doc or docx folder. Heres my html code:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload">
<input type="submit">
```

And here's the code for upload_file.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]));

    if (($_FILES["upload"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            if (file_exists("Proposals/".$_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
                "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

But this won't upload anything even though it replied back with with a successful message. I'm thinking it's because it won't let me create a directory. Is there anything wrong with the above code or do I have to add some more code to make it create a directory. Here my folder structure if it helps at all:

[image: Folder]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create destination (Folder) in PHP while using move\_uploaded\_file()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384951/how-to-create-destination-folder-in-php-while-using-move-uploaded-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to create the directory you're trying to move the file to, it won't automatically get created by move_uploaded_file.

Use mkdir(), http://php.net/mkdir, to create the directory and then move the file.

Here's an alternative ending to your script, which should do

```
// Create directory if it does not exist
if(!is_dir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/")) {
    mkdir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/");
}

// Move the uploaded file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);

// Output location
echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
```

Comment: This code is a great starting point (error handling being left to the reader, of course).The only enhancement I would suggest would be to use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of hard-coding the "/"

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the directory exists, and if not, create it.

```
if (!file_exists("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"])) {
      mkdir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading file to directory that does not exist so you need to create it first, your upload_file.php should be like

```
<?php
session_start();
$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]));

if (($_FILES["upload"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("Proposals/".$_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if directory exists if not create it 
            if(!is_dir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/")) {
               mkdir("Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/");
             }
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
            "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/". $_SESSION["FirstName"] ."/". $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```