# script upload file doesn't upload into uuid folder

Tags: php, file-upload, uuid

i'm creating in my localhost (files will not be published in remote server), a web app where i add some features i need. One of them is upload a wav file, who i want to upload into a different folder for each upload.
I used that code that works with normal folder. I edited it in add some options i need (remove blank space in file name etc.), but when i put the "$folderUuid" into the "move_upload_file", the folder is created, but the file isn't uploaded into.

Another feature that i won't be able to understand where to add is to create a uuid folder only when a file is uploaded, not every time the page is refreshed. I read that discussion [PHP File Upload Creating Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700013/php-file-upload-creating-directory) and understand that i have to use the $_SESSION, but my code doesn't work.

Here is the php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$allowedExts = array("wav");
$fileName =   $_FILES['file']['name'];
$extension = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1); 

 if(!is_dir("inputFiles/". $_SESSION["folder"] ."/")) {
    mkdir(uniqid('inputFiles/'), 0700). $_SESSION["folder"] ."/" ;

}
if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "File kind: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";

    if (file_exists("inputFiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " file già esistente. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folderUuid . str_replace(" ", "",$_FILES["file"]["name"])); 
      print "<br />";
      echo "Saved in: " . "inputFiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      print "<br />";
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
}
```

Here is the html code:

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 

<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Hope someone can help me to fix that problems.
Kind Regards
Brus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

 //create directory from the file
 $temp = explode('.', $file_name);
 $dir = $temp[0];
 $extension = strtolower($temp[1]);
 $allowedExts = array("wav");

if(!is_dir('inputFiles/'.$dir)){
    mkdir("inputFiles/$dir",0700);
}
if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
 echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
 }
 else
 {
echo "Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "File kind: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";

if (file_exists("inputFiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " file già esistente. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, "inputFiles/".$dir."/".$file_name); 
  print "<br />";
  echo "Saved in: " . "inputFiles/$dir/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  print "<br />";
  }
  }
  }
   else
 {
   echo "Invalid file";
  }

 }
```

Comment: Not create a uuid but a folder with name as filename, but it help anyway. Thanks a lot. Regards