# How to create a directory inside a directory in yii2 and upload file into that directory

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have a form

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
 <?php echo $form->field($userformmodel, 'user_image')->fileInput(); ?>
 <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I am uploading a file in the form and submit

```
In the model I have written the code as

 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg']
    ];
}

 public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->user_image->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->user_image->baseName . '.' . $this->user_image->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my controller

```
 public function actionProfile()
{
 $model = new UserProfile();
 $userformmodel = new UserForm();
 $model->user_image = UploadedFile::getInstance($userformmodel, 'user_image');
 if($model->save(false))
                {
                $model->upload();        
                }
 }
```

This is just creating a directory called `uploads`. But I want to create a directory inside uploads directory for each user i.e, based upon the primary key in database table `user` I want to create and name the directory name.

Example, if the user registering is saved as primarykey **4**, then a directory with name **4** must be created and the file he uploads must be saved into that directory.

How to make this happen? please help.

Comment: Well, you should simply create dir before... What did you try ?

Comment: I didn't try anything as I dint find any relative solution. How to create a sub directory

Comment: Did you search ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384951/how-to-create-destination-folder-in-php-while-using-move-uploaded-file

Comment: Is it the same in case of yii2? or do we have any widgets for the same?

Comment: I would not recommend using the primary key for directory name (especially when the directory is publically accessible). create a unique token as directory name, create the directory with mkdir() (and chmod()) and upload your file to this destination. Store the directory name in database to link to user

Answer (score 10):

In yii2, you can use 'yii\helpers\FileHelper' to create folders.

```
FileHelper::createDirectory($path, $mode = 0775, $recursive = true);
```

In your case:

```
public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $path = 'uploads/'. USERNAMEHERE .'/'. date('YMD');
        FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
        $this->user_image->saveAs($path .'/'. $this->user_image->baseName . '.' . $this->user_image->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

Use 'yii\helpers\FileHelper' in your model file.

Step 2:

In the model file where you are writing the save file function, add these lines:

```
if ($this->validate()) {
    $path = 'uploads/'. USERNAMEHERE .'/'. date('YMD');
    FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
    $this->user_image->saveAs($path .'/'. $this->user_image->baseName . '.' . $this->user_image->extension);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for creating directory inside another directory and storing the file according to year->month->file_name using yii framework
    year - parent directory,
    month - sub directory

Then finally storing the file in month directory:

```
 $new_file_name   = $_FILES['Book']['name']['image'];
            $path=YII::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/resources/uploads/';
            $year_folder = $path . date("Y");
            $month_folder = $year_folder . '/' . date("m");


            // change umask to '0' by default to make folder with full permissions
            $oldmask = umask(0);

            /*
            for reference
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions
            */

            !file_exists($year_folder) && mkdir($year_folder , 0777);
            !file_exists($month_folder) && mkdir($month_folder, 0777);
            umask($oldmask);

            $path = $month_folder . '/' . $new_file_name;
            $res = move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Book']['tmp_name']
                                                    ['image'],$path);
            chmod($path, 0666);
```